# backend isnt generating any routes

Tags: typescript, routes, nestjs

my backend code that I'm doing with Nest and TypeORM is compiling and executing, but, it doesn't generate any routes, the only route that makes is the swagger, and even the swagger is getting no routes besides itself.
[image: print of swagger http://localhost:3000/api#/]

main.ts:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  
  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Backend Crud')
    .setDescription('API para o crud')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('Devs & Niveis')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);
  await app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
  console.log(`Application is running on: ${await app.getUrl()}`);
}
bootstrap();
```

The rest of my code is here: https://github.com/GabrielOGW/Crud-Project/tree/main/backend

I was expecting that the routes would appear on the log or swagger api.

Comment: I quickly had a look at you repo, you are not importing the modules dev and nivel in the app module, so the controllers can not be read

Answer (score 0):

As was said on the comments, the sollution found was importing the modules to the app module.

Thanks Jerome for helping me.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Nivel } from './nivel/entities/nivel.entity';
import { Dev } from './devs/entities/dev.entity';
import { NivelModule } from './nivel/nivel.module';
import { DevsModule } from './devs/devs.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'password',
      database: 'crud',
      entities: [Nivel, Dev],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    NivelModule,
    DevsModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`NivelModule, DevsModule,`